# Непростой деликатный вопрос об одном обсценном слове (18+)

Tags: словообразование, суффиксы, обсценная-лексика

Приветствую уважаемое сообщество и сразу прошу прощения за задаваемый вопрос.

Но меня очень давно интересует такая странность в значении матершиного слова "е..ало". Дело в том, что слово это означает "лицо", иногда "голова", но сам тип словообразования должен указывать совсем на иное значение. Ибо окончание ало, ило указывает на некий предмет, с помощью которого производится действие (кадило - то, чем кадят, гасило - то, чем гасят, накрайняк бучало - то, чем бучат, шумят). Как известно, создатель Эсперанто даже внес в язык славянский суффикс il, именно для обозначения предметов благодаря которым производится действие. 
Ситуация усугубляется современной словоформой вышеуказанного обсценного словца "е..альник", что так же напрямую указывает на предмет, благодаря чему (паяльник - им паяют, купальник - с его помощью купаются). Это наводит на мысль, что подсознательно даже абсолютно незадумывающиеся люди употребляющие абсценную лексику выбирают словоформы наиболее адекватно отвечающие современному состоянию языка, но при этом сохраняя сам тип словообразования. Но словообразование это вроде как противоречит смыслу. Или я чего-то все-таки недопонимаю, почему и обращаюсь к сообществу за комментариями, или ох уж и странная анатомия у этих русских.

Еще раз пардон за вопрос на грани троллинга, но мне правда жутко интересно. Такое не узнать больше нигде, окромя как в интернетах! Беглый гуглинг не дал абсолютно никаких результатов по исследуемому вопросу.

Comment: По основному вопросу пока ничего сказать не могу. Споткнулся на слове "абсценном"...  В словарях -- **обсценный** (первая буква -- О).

Comment: С учетом предыдущего замечания и исходя из общего уровня академичности в формулировках автора полагаю, что вопрос надо квалифицировать как псевдонаучный. Или просто троллинг. Дело не в "абсценном" вопросе, мат для филологов сам по себе не является для филологов табуированной темой, но сам подход ниже всякой критики.

Comment: Известно, что подобные ненормативные образования не подчиняются общей логике морфов и их семантике (не буду дразнить модеров, примеры приводя, они общеизвестны). Автор с умным видом о предмете рассуждающий не может о том не знать.

Comment: [Ответ на английском](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/6831/551).

Comment: Ну не совсем... Там общие рассуждения на тему "инструментального" суффикса  (соответвующего нашему творительному падежу, известному в иноязычных грамматиках русского как Instrumentalis). Для любого русского, кстати, интуитивно понятные до прозрачности. А здесь ставится вопрос ребром - как это слово могло образоваться с таким суффиксом. Так что я бы поостерегся закрывать вопрос таким образом.

Comment: Посмешили нападками на "о" "а". Я, конечно, изначально отдавал себе отчет задавая подобный вопрос в мекке Граммарнаци, но, если уж придираться к ошибкам, то до конца уж вспотыкаться и на глобально неверной расстановке запятых, не говоря уж о прочих неверных "дилекатностях". Но, в целом, понятно, матюги правилами не регулируются, поэтому и х.. с ними? :))

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, у слова два значения: "лицо" и "рот", а ещё есть слово "е-ло" (варианты "ё-ыч", "е-учка" и прочее), означающее только лицо. Вполне возможно, что "е-альник" изначально применялся в отношении рта, по аналогии словом "умывальник", "сральник" — то есть то место, в которое можно осуществлять данное действие, то есть "е-альник" — это об оральном сексе. А дальнейшее развитие слова уже пошло по непредсказуемому сценарию, перенеся его значение на всё лицо, в конце концов, на английском же есть выражение "fuck my face", так почему в русском языке в отношении лица нельзя не использовать "е-альник". Ну а "е-ло" и прочие формы — это уже, скорее, вне законов словообразования.